# Al hacer clic en un botón, no aparece el texto en el jTextfield, pero si luego se hace clic en un segundo botón y luego al primero, sí lo hace

Tags: java, java-swing

Cuando le doy al botón "Nuevo" el jTextfield (numeroTicket) debería recibir un valor, que realmente no lo captura, pero si le doy al botón "Cancelar", acto seguido al botón "Nuevo" sí aparece lo que necesito que salga en el jTextfield, en el último if se manipula el campo de texto; borré algunas líneas de código pero el punto es que logré a través de un try catch que desde el primer momento que se presionase "Nuevo" el jtextfield estuviese lleno pero al segundo intento ya no genera el número deseado y retorna ceros (es decir lo opuesto a lo que pasa actualmente).

El try catch lo que hacía era: `noTicket = ObtenerCorrelativoTicket();`

```
this.numeroTicket.setText("");
this.numeroTicket.setText("0"); // o cualquier otro valor predeterminado deseado


int noTicket = 0;

// Establecer el valor del cuadro de texto "numeroTicket"
//this.numeroTicket.setText(String.format("%05d", noTicket));

// Resto del código del método "btnNuevoActionPerformed"
if(!RegistroManual.isSelected()){
    String numeroTarjeta = null;
        try {
            numeroTarjeta = lector();
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(taquilla2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    Persona persona = new Persona();
    persona = obtenerDatosBasicos(numeroTarjeta);
    if(persona.getIdentificacion() == null){
    falloCarnet = true;
    numCarnet.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setVisible(true);
    status.setText("No se han obtenido datos.");
    status2.setText("Por favor ingresarlos manualmente");
    status3.setText("e ingrese el numero del carnet.");
    status.setForeground(status2.getForeground());
    }else{
    status.setText("Datos obtenidos.");
    status.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    
    this.cedula.setText(persona.getIdentificacion());
    this.nombres.setText(persona.getNombre());
    this.apellidos.setText(persona.getApellido());
    } else{
    this.cedula.setText(null);
    this.nombres.setText(null);
    this.apellidos.setText(null);    
    }
    
    this.jList1.removeAll();//opción1
    
    
    
    try {
        llenarCBEventos();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(taquilla2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      
                
    modelo.removeAllElements();
            
    try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    leerConfigTxt();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(taquilla2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 500);

        ArrayList apartados = connect.ObtenerApartados(Integer.parseInt(terminal));
        int noButaca = (int) apartados.get(1);

        if (noTicket == 0 && noButaca == 0) {
            noButaca = Integer.parseInt(ObtenerNumeroButaca());
            noTicket = ObtenerCorrelativoTicket();
            connect.ApartarCorrelativos(noTicket, noButaca, terminal);
            connect.ActualizarCorrelativo();
            connect.ActualizarCorrelativoButaca();
        }

        // agregar verificación de cadena vacía
        String noButacaStr = Integer.toString(noButaca);
        
        if (noButacaStr.isEmpty()) {
           numeroTicket.setText(String.format("%05d", 1));
        } else {
            numeroTicket.setText(String.format("%05d", noButaca));
        }
      
       
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(taquilla2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // manejar el caso en que la cadena está vacía
    }
```

Comment: Hola, coloca puntos de interrupción en las partes problemática de tu código y examina en esos puntos los valores de tus variables.